# Why my heroku node.js app is giving at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am trying to run my simple node app on Heroku.

Here is the directory structure

```
├── app.js
├── assets
├── blog.html
├── index.html
├── node_modules
└── package.json
```

Here is my app.js

```
let express = require('express'),
    path = require('path');
var app = express();
let server = require('http').Server(app);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname)));

app.get('/', function(req, res, next){
    res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.get('/blog.html', function(req, res,next){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+"/blog.html"));
});

app.post('/contact', function(req, res, next){

});
server.listen('8000', function() {
    console.log("App is running on port 8000");
});
```

Here is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "website",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines" : {
    "node" : "6.3.1",
    "npm" : "3.10.3"
  },
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start" : "node app.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.14.0"
  }
}
```

When I go to the console it rightly prints app is starting at xxxx port.
But then the app crashes with the following message

```
2016-08-10T13:12:49.839138+00:00 app[web.1]: App is running on port xxxx
2016-08-10T13:13:34.944963+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=saras-website.herokuapp.com request_id=28d8705a-d5a4-4aaa-bd8d-4c4c6101fbd4 fwd="106.51.20.181" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-08-10T13:13:48.295315+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-08-10T13:13:48.552740+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=saras-website.herokuapp.com request_id=b77e151f-7017-482d-b4ba-15d980534fd7 fwd="106.51.20.181" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-08-10T13:13:50.163466+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=saras-website.herokuapp.com request_id=1e7b57e5-1056-4cb3-b41f-cd3f11794efe fwd="106.51.20.181" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong here... Help is appreciated

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Set port like this

ES5:

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
```

And

```
server.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("App is running on port " + port);
});
```

ES6:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
```

And

```
server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("App is running on port " + port);
});
```

This allows Heroku to set the port at run time.

Comment: Yes...I figured it out... There was another message like `Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch` I googled that and found the answer. Will accept it in next 6 mins

Comment: There's also a page about setting the port properly in the Heroku documentation for those interested : https://help.heroku.com/P1AVPANS/why-is-my-node-js-app-crashing-with-an-r10-error

Comment: I am getting the same error when deploying the latest angular app using Heroku, I m building just angular app without express or any server file