# Heroku error on Rails app : error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

How I can solve the error. I see build success and no error. But I am not able to see the rails app working on the link.

I see these lines in the log file :

```
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=some_id_here fwd="47.247.8.241" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why my heroku node.js app is giving at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874760/why-my-heroku-node-js-app-is-giving-at-error-code-h10-desc-app-crashed-method)

Answer (score 4):

```
$heroku restart
```

And if it didn't work use

```
$heroku run rails console
```

will give you the details on why the app has crashed