# Error while deploying project in heroku with error code=H10 desc = "App crashed"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, mern

After trying to fix the below error for many days, I decided to post the error, hoping that someone can help me to figure it out.
**Note**: I added a link to my git repository as well.

Here is the error of my log:

> 2020-05-04T17:42:26.314508+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
>   host=cactus-restaurant.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=202dfecf-cfb0-4349-bd51-101b4f481ace fwd="91.139.187.213"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

**github** : https://github.com/Teodora321/Cactus-Restaurant

Comment: This [post](https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/node-app-on-heroku-getting-application-error/170632) might help.

Comment: These posts [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14322989/2873538), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17180495/2873538), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38874760/2873538) might also help.

Comment: Yeah, i saw it but nothing from there solve my problem.